# Where can I set path to make.exe on Windows?

Tags: c++, registry, makefile, path, msys

When I try run `make` from cmd-console on Windows, it runs Turbo Delphi's `make.exe` but I need MSYS's `make.exe`. There is no mention about Turbo Delphi in `%path%` variable, maybe I can change it to MSYS in registry?

Comment: This question should be re-written to be more high-level eg "how to append/update path environment variable on Windows", since the question is specific to a particular .exe file.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The path is in the registry but usually you edit through this interface:

1. Go to `Control Panel` -> `System` -> `System settings` -> `Environment Variables`.
2. Scroll down in system variables until you find `PATH`.
3. Click edit and change accordingly.
4. BE SURE to include a semicolon at the end of the previous as that is the delimiter, i.e. `c:\path;c:\path2`
5. Launch a new console for the settings to take effect.

Comment: no effect, still Borlans's make.exe runs. I think it must be in registry, because
>>There is no mention about Turbo Delphi in %path% variable

Comment: OK, when I tried "echo %path%" I saw Turbo Delphi's path in the middle of the long string. Thank you and sorry for inattention.

Comment: Windows 10 has a few ways of arriving there now, and includes a new GUI for managing entries so you don't need to remember that pesky semi-colon anymore: http://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10

Comment: Use the Windows command "where" to find out where make.exe lives.
For example:

    "where make.exe"

Gives this result on my computer:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Bin\make.exe

If I had make.exe in other paths, it would show those.

Comment: It would be easier to RUN or CMD/PowerShell to: rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables

This future-proofs it as MS keeps fiddling with the GUI.

Comment: OMG :) Microsoft using this page as a part of documentation and guiding .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/get-started-windows-bash?tabs=bash

Comment: @user8231110
  Ha ha ha Yes.

Answer (score 54):

Here I'm providing solution to setup Terraform environment variable in windows for beginners.

1. Download the terraform ZIP file from Terraform site.
2. Extract the .exe from the ZIP file to a folder eg C:\Apps\Terraform
   copy this path location like C:\Apps\terraform\
3. Add the folder location to your PATH variable, eg: `Control Panel -> System -> System settings -> Environment Variables`

In `System Variables`, select `Path` > `edit` > `new` > Enter the location of the Terraform .exe, eg `C:\Apps\Terraform` then click `OK`

[image]

5. Open a new CMD/PowerShell and the Terraform command should work

Comment: What does this have to do with the question asked?

Comment: Hello @MarkRotteveel, I hve not asked question here, just I provided how to setup enviroment varible for terraform in windows

Comment: The question is about running MSYS make.exe from the windows command prompt. That has nothing to to with terraform. Your answer doesn't belong here.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel agree but the 'mistake' is being fed from https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/install

Comment: @MattBracewell Nothing in the question suggests that has anything to do with it, and Terraform didn't even exist when this question was asked back in 2009.

Comment: I got here from learn.microsoft.com

Answer (score 15):

Or you can just run this PowerShell command to append extra folder to the existing path:

```
$env:Path += ";C:\temp\terraform"
```

Comment: Powershell would not detect my environmentVar changes until i ran this powershell command, thank you

Comment: As far as I can tell this is only temporary - I added an answer to fix that.

Comment: This is an awesome solution.

Answer (score 8):

To add a PERSISTENT path (eg one that's permanent), you can do this one-liner in PowerShell (adjust the last c:\apps\terraform part)

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH -Value  (((Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).path) + ";c:\apps\terraform" )
```

Alternatively, you can jump directly to the Environment Variables dialog by RUNning/CMD/PowerShell this:

```
rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had issues for a whilst not getting Terraform commands to run unless I was in the directory of the exe, even though I set the path correctly.

For anyone else finding this issue, I fixed it by moving the environment variable higher than others!

Comment: I tried but no use still unable to find terraform commands. Any other suggestions can you provide?

Comment: My issue was: I was adding the full path of the exe file. You must ONLY add the directory path. NOT the 'terraform' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a bat file `makedos.bat` containing the following line?

```
c:\DOS\make.exe %1 %2 %5
```

and put it in `C:\DOS` (or `C:\Windows`è or make sure that it is in your `%path%`)

You can run from cmd, SET and it displays all environment variables, including PATH.

In registry you can find environment variables under:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment`

Answer (score -1):

just copy it to system32 call make1 or whatever if the name conflicts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).