# vagrant is not a recognised internal/external command

Tags: vagrant

I have cloned a repository from Github following a course on Udacity. It contains a vagrant file and according to the tutorial I shoulld use `vagrant up` command to get the virtual machine started. But it says that `vagrant` is not a recognized internal/external command. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you install Vagrant? https://www.vagrantup.com/

Comment: No.The tutorial says that download will begin after the statement is executed.

Comment: I haven't seen the tutorial, but if you run `vagrant` without having installed Vagrant, your computer has no idea what you're talking about. If I had to guess, I would say it is saying a VM image or something else would download after you run the command. But to use Vagrant, you necessarily have to have installed it on the system first.

Answer (score 0):

Install Vagrant for Windows, if your machine OS is windows.
https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html

Restart computer.
Install Virtualbox from Virtualbox SDK
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
VirtualBox 5.2.6 platform packages. The binaries are released under the terms of the GPL version 2.
 **Windows hosts**

Once Virtual box is installed, run the command on the cmd prompt.
vagrant up --provision

Answer (score -1):

I'm in the same course on Udacity and I think the issue you are having can be resolved by adding C:\Hashicorp\Vagrant\bin to your system variables path.

Instructions for editing your path can be found here: [Where can I set path to make.exe on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618280/where-can-i-set-path-to-make-exe-on-windows)

This fixed the error for me.