# make third_party not functioning while installing Google or-tools from source - Windows

Tags: python, windows, svn, or-tools

I'm relatively new to Python programming and developing in general, so I was astonished to see I had a lot of luck [installing Google or-tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/installing#installing-from-source). That was, up until this command: `$ make third_party`. The command is not recognized:

```
C:\Users\dbaug\Documents\Google Optimization\or-tools>make third_party
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If I move to the `tools` sub-directory, where the `make.exe` file is located, the command is recognized but produces an error:

```
C:\Users\dbaug\Documents\Google Optimization\or-tools\tools>make third_party
g++     Makefile.cc   -o Makefile
process_begin: CreateProcess((null), g++ Makefile.cc -o Makefile, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile] Error 2
```

Now I completed every step along the way (installed CMake and the Java JDK, etc.), including adding GLPK and SCIP to the dependencies, and also added all of the executables to my `PATH`, adding the bins from VS2015, CMake, and TortoiseSVN that I installed despite the Google instructions not clearly stating to.

I know SVN is supposed to interface with the `Makefile` in the or-tools repository, but it doesn't seem to recognize it - could it be something with choosing TortoiseSVN over another option? What am I doing wrong?

Also there is no terminal in the Tools menu of Microsoft Visual Studios 2015 - are they asking me to use the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015?

Answer (score 4):

Just run tools\make third_party

Answer (score 1):

By moving to the tools subdirectory, the 'make' utility tries to compile against the file named "Makefile" located in this directory.

The Makefile you need to compile against is at the root of the source folder. This means that one possible solution is to add the 'or-tools/tools/' folder to your path, then run make from the or-tools root folder.

Answer (score 1):

@Laurent Perron, @fkorsa they have explained clearly enough.

I just add some details for adding "or-tools\tools" folder to the path:

> 1. Go to Control Panel -> System -> System settings -> Environment Variables.
> 2. Scroll down in system variables until you find PATH.
> 3. Click edit and change accordingly.
> 4. BE SURE to include a semicolon at the end of the previous as that is the delimiter, i.e. c:\path;c:\path2
> 5. Launch a new console for the settings to take effect.

[Where can I set path to make.exe on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618280/where-can-i-set-path-to-make-exe-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

In the console prompt you can also use:

```sh
set PATH=%PATH%;tools;tools\win
```

then now you can type:

```
make detect
```